# Jquery only allow numeric field with unique and limited digit

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want jquery script that allow only numeric field unique number with only 4 digit allow.

HTML

```
<input type="text" id="registration_number" class="input-sm" name="registration_number" maxlength="6" required>
```

my jQuery code is working but i also take **duplicate** value.

```
 jQuery("#job_no").keypress(function(e) { 

    var verified = (e.which == 8 || e.which == undefined || e.which == 0) ? null : String.fromCharCode(e.which).match(/[^0-9]/);
    if (verified || e.delegateTarget.value.length>3 || e.ctrlKey ==true) { if(e.which!=8 ){e.preventDefault();}}

}).on('paste',function(e){ e.preventDefault();});
```

i am new in jquery so how could i do this?

someone please help me.

Comment: i dont know why you are using input type='text' instead you can easily achieve this with input type='number' and for length you can provide min=0 and max=9999. this wont allow more than 4 digits

Comment: what do you mean by unique ?

Answer (score 0):

```
var myInput = $("#registration_number").val();
if($.isNumeric(myInput)) {
  var myInputNum = parseInt(myInput);
  if(myInputNum < 10000) {
     // do things here
  }

}
```